# jade extends keyword issues in express.js

Tags: express, pug

Alright, so I am having an issue with express getting my templates to work with the extends/block keywords. I was able to get the index template working just fine; however, when I tried to add a second template, 'extends' does not seem to function. I've pasted the code below, and help would be appreciated! (for reference, I am running express version 2.5.8 and node 0.6.12)

app.js:

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes');

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

// Configuration

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({ secret: 'your secret here' }));
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.set('view options', { layout: false, pretty: true });
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

// Routes

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/login', routes.login);

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port,     app.settings.env);
});
```

routes/index.js:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'rm-dash-r' })
};

exports.login = function (req, res) {
    res.render('login', { title: 'rm-dash-r' })
};
```

In the views/ directory, there are 3 files. index.jade, main-layout.jade, and login.jade. For testing, login and index are identical files.

main-layout.jade:

```
!!!
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body(style='margin: 0 22%;')
    div.container
        div.header
            a(href='/')
                span rm-dash-r

        div.stripes
            span

        div.nav
            a(href='/') Blog
            a(href='/') About
            a(href='/') Projects
            div.clearer
                span

        div.stripes
            span

        div.main
            div.left
                div.content

                    block content
...
```

index.jade/login.jade:

```
extends main-layout

block content
    h1 testing
```

Essentially, the route for '/' works without any problems, but the login route will only render the login.jade markup, except with extends main-layout at the top of the page.

If there is any other information that would be helpful to know, please let me know.

Comment: I ran your code and wasn't able to reproduce the error you are talking about. Is there something else in main-layout after the content block? If yes, try removing it and see if the outputs differs.

Comment: tried removing the code afterwards and still am seeing the same issue. You were able to get both the / and the /login route to function correctly? What versions of express/node/jade are on your system? Thanks.

Comment: jade: 0.21.0  |  node v0.6.18  |  express: 2.5.8   ... do u have the code hosted online? If not, i'll try to create one on github :)

Comment: I'm hosting the git repo on my personal server to make testing easier, but if you'd like a copy to see if you can re-produce the issue, I can send you one. I was able to fix it using the answer below though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright, after significant trial and error, I seem to have it working. For some reason, after adding a return to the first line of login.jade (ie. extends main-layout is now line 2) it all seems to work.

I haven't the slightest idea why this is the case, but if anybody can shed some light I'd be interested to hear.